# Why some non-root program can be executed by double-click while others not?

Tags: executable

For example, I found Firefox's process command line: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox. I browse to this location and double-click it, it prompts this:

[image]

However, if I type the command in terminal, it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple reason is that file manager recognizes the file type. If you double-click `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` or any other `.desktop` file for that matter, the file manager will execute it as application. Otherwise, file manager looks up which filetype corresponds to which application.

And that's were `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` comes in. It is compiled as shared object.

```
$ file   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d2a4bfe9dbe1aadd5480a6b5612b7a3fc1fd01a2, stripped
```

This type of file has been touched on in detail in [kos's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/690646/295286), but basically shared object is an executable file, which can be used as library. Libraries usually are included into other software, hence Nautilus can ignore and has no default program assigned to it. By contrast, to shell (or rather kernel, to which `execve()` call will pass the path to that file) recognizes that as executable file just fine.

Now, what gets executed when you execute `firefox.desktop` ? That's `/usr/bin/firefox.sh` - a wrapper script which does a few checks and replaces itself with `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` later on. In this case, shell script is detected as filetype and Nautilus happily spawns that. There's a lot of other things that happen behind the scenes, but that's the general gist of it all.